# Transfer Clash of Clans village with iOS 6

Tags: clash-of-clans

I would like to know if there is any way to transfer your village in clash of clans using iOS 6. I recently erased all the data of my iPod and re-downloaded all my apps. I opened clash of clans with my old Game Center and tried to get my village back but I received a message saying i need iOS 7 or higher to transfer my village, but I can't upgrade since I only have an iPod fourth gen. How can I get my village back?

Answer (score -1):

i got this too but i think you might want to see this vid:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9Ndjzr89B8

it might help u to ix ur prbolem u dont reall  need ios7 device just one with ur base. in ur case u do need ios 7 device may be ur brothers? or dads?